# Area enclosed by a semi-circular fence

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

A contractor has installed a silt fence around an area that is semi-circular and level to prevent soil from the construction site entering nearby streams. The diameter of the semi-circle is 900 feet. How many linear feet of fence does the contractor need to use to enclose the area? 
How many acres are within the enclosed by the fence?
I need an answer for part two of the question.

Comment: Are you trying to solve by yourself or only pasting the problem here?

Comment: I tried to solve it but i am having problems with the second part. thanks

Comment: So you can write what you did ans we can give you some hints.

Comment: Area of a whole circle =$\pi r^2$, and according to Google 43560 square ft to an acre.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'd like to tell you a few things that will likely improve the reception of your question. Your title does not indicate the content of the problem. Nor does your tag. This means that people have no way of knowing that they're interested in your problem (unless they click on it, but why would they when there are other, better indicated problems?). You have also just copy-pasted the question. Many people here expect you to put in some effort before they put in the effort to help.

Comment: I calculate the semicircle perimeter which is equal to the perimeter of a circle divided by 2 and then add a diameter to get the answer of the first question.

Comment: @Maesumi You've already done the work; you should turn your comment into an answer.

Comment: what about the second part of the question which is " How many acres are within the enclosed by the fence?"

Comment: For the second part, see Maesumi's hint. That should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Area of the whole circle is $\pi r^2=\pi 450^2$. For a semi circle it is $\pi  450^2/2$. In acres this is $\pi 450^2/(2*43560)=7.30$